# How to install MYSQL driver in H2 Console

Tags: jdbc, h2, mysql-connector

I have an online MYSQL server and wish to edit query of it by using H2 Console. I have downloaded mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar and place it inside the /bin folder of H2 folder in my pc program files. But I still cannot connect to the server, it says Class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" not found [90086-200]. Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/3217656/269514

Answer (score 3):

I never tried it before and I was surprised the H2 console web application can actually connect to other databases so easily.

You'll need to add MySQL's JDBC driver (MySQL 8.x in this example) in the command line when launching the H2 Console, as in:

```
$ java -cp <h2-driver>:<mysql-driver> org.h2.tools.Console
```

In my case this looked like:

```
$ java -cp jdbc-drivers/h2-1.4.197.jar:jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar org.h2.tools.Console
```

With this command the H2 Console application shows up in the browser and you can connect to the MySQL 8.x database using the parameters similar to (adjust as needed):

- Driver Class: **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver**
- JDBC URL: **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase**
- User Name: **my_username**
- Password: **my_password**

Click "Connect" and it goes in. Then you can run any SQL statement, such as:

```
select version();
```

And it shows:

```
version()  
------------
8.0.3-rc-log

(1 row, 17 ms)
```

Awesome!

Comment: Most JDBC clients can be used with databases other than that which the vendor intends. I use [TOAD](https://download.freedownloadmanager.org/Mac-OS/Toad/FREE-2.4.2.html) from Oracle for most of my database work.

Comment: I type in the command line but it shows "Error: Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.Console". Still cannot get through this problem. I run this in the folder Program Files/H2/bin where my h2.-1.4.200.jar is located.

Comment: @lalala If you are on Windows, you need to separate classpath entries with a semicolon (`;`) instead of a colon (`:`).